# Product in category not showing when search that term (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, search, categories, product

If I have a category called 'Vegetarian', but no products with that exact word in it, then search for 'vegetarian', no products display.

Is this how Magento works? If so, is there a way to include any products in a matching category? If not, what would be causing this issue?

I have already cleared the cache, reindexed the data, checked the quantity, visibility, and made sure it is included in the proper categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category name is not searched for returning a list of matching items with the quick search box. The fields that do get searched are set up under `Catalog->Manage Attributes`. There you can assign the attribute to be `Use in Quick Search` or `Use in Advanced Search`.

For your case, I would recommend adding a field called "Search Tags" and make it searchable, but never displayed. This will let you assign products to be found without having to actually contain the word(s) in the description.